Question on Lebesgue Measure from Measures, Integrals and Martingales.
I have a question from the book Measures, Integrals and Martingales by René L. Schilling.
Its related to Thm 5.8)ii), pg: 35 (written below). What does satisfies $\kappa = \mu([0,1]^n) < \infty$ even mean? And what is n in this case? If someone could please intuitively explain what ii) is trying to state, that would be great. Thanks in advance!
Theorem 5.8
(i) The n-dimensional Lebesgue measure $\lambda^n$ is invariant under translations, i.e.
$$
\lambda^n(x + B) = \lambda^n(B) \quad \forall x \in \mathbb{R}^n, \, \forall B \in \mathscr{B}(\mathbb{R}^n). \tag{5.3}
$$
(ii) Every measure $\mu$ on $(\mathbb{R}^n, \mathscr{B}(\mathbb{R}^n))$ which is invariant under translations and satisfies $\kappa = \mu([0,1]^n) < \infty$ is a multiple of Lebesgue measure: $\mu = \kappa \lambda^n$.

The unit cube of $\mathbb R^n$ is usually denoted as $[0,1]^n$, that is, the set of $n$-uples $(x_1,\dots,x_n)$ such that $0\leqslant x_i\leqslant n$ for each $i\in\{1,\dots,n\}$. The condition $\mu([0,1]^n)<\infty$ means that
the measure $\mu$ of the unit cube is finite (which may not be always the case). If this quantity is finite, then the author defines this as $\kappa$. This notation is needed in order to express $\mu$ as a multiple of Lebesgue measure.
The statement is valid for any $n\geqslant 1$.
